# Lot of forms in a single app view, how to handle?

Tags: forms, mobile-application, drop-down-list

I need to put about 20 <input type="text"> in a single form in my ionic app and i can't use tabs view. 
I also need to ask user to select some data in a dropdown list that load data from the back-end. The problem is that the user need to be able to scroll in that dropdown without losing focus.

What is the best way to handle this situation without tabs view and how can I show datas while the user is typing in the field?

Also can you provide me some examples of apps that are similar to my case (lot of fields in a single form)?

**Note:** the app is material design like so it has to be user friendly.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT :** I was thinking about using some modal views and split the form in 3 or 4 section. Is this duable and user friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to handle a similar situation like this recently. You can try having each question on a single page and track the users progress with a fluid progress bar (dots will just highlight the length).

For the dropdown, you can have a scrollable dropdown view, so the user can scroll that instead of the page without loosing focus.

Comment: Not all the fields are required but I have to show them anyway. I was thinking that I can split the form in some section with ionic modals and show a sum on the form page or something that shows that you successfully insert all the required fields in that particular section. Is this good?

Comment: Hard to tell when i've no idea who your intended users are or what the survey is for. The sum idea seems a little unnecessary. You could just have in greyed out writing under the field alerting the user that the field is optional

Comment: That is true, i'm working on it right now and i still wanna try that sum thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can split the form and ask user to fill it which improves experience.

1) You may categorize the fields by which are mandatory and optional one.

2) we can use progress bar or navigation (step1 -> 2 ->3) for marking progress. The important thing here is usrr should able to go to prev screens form fields.

3) you may ask user to fill optional fields in the last page/modal view with "skip for now" and submit.

4) also user need to have cancel or exit button in all form pages.

5) also if possible please analyse whether u can get details from social media or any other different medium.. so that u can reduce the burden of user filling out all fields further.